# Click event not working on a div appended dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

When i search any thing in autocomplete textbox google appends some divs in my html ,

```
<div class="pac-container" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; width: 134px; left: 885px; top: 412px; display: none;">
    <div class="pac-item remove">This is me </div>
  <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>ustralia</div>
  <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>bbas Town, Karachi, Sind, Pakistan</div>
  <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>ustria</div>
  <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>rgentina</div><div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>rizona</div></div>
```

now you can notice that first child ion `pac-container` is not like others , i added that div dynamically for some purpose . Now if i want to bind a event to that div then i doesn't work .

here is what i am doing

```
$('.remove').live('click', function () {
   console.log("working");
});
```

Thanks in advance .
**Update**

I think you guys misunderstand me , if i put my dynamic div into any other place except `pac-container` , then it works but when i put my div in `pac-container` then it doesn't work and i tried almost everyone's solution but no one works .
Hope now you guys understand the scenario . Thanks

**Update 2**

this is the [link](http://ahsanashfaq.com/index.html) where i upload my working

Comment: If you don't show us some more code, how are we to know what is wrong with it ? As all of the answers below prove, the procided code works fine, so the problem lies in some part of code not given in your answer. Idea: Why don't you prepare a **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)** for us ? Or a fiddle would help...

Comment: @ExpertSystem see my Update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which version of jquery you are using but as of `jquery 1.7` `live` has been deprecated in favour of `on`, so you can replace your `live` binding with this one:

```
 $('.pack-container').on('click', '.remove', function(){
     console.log("working");
  });
```

If `pack-container` is also a dynamically created element then you would need to revise the above to be:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
     console.log("working");
  });
```

Official documentation here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
   console.log("working");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.remove', function () {
   //Your code
});
```

You should delegate the event using `.on`. By the way `.live` is outdated. Instead use `.on` method. The problem is dynamically added elements are not available on the page load to bind events to them. Therefore error occurs. Try binding the event to the patent which is in your case could be another div or `document` would be fine.

Read more

[Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code its working correctly.I think you are doing this click function in dom ready function.If you try click function for dynamic element in dom ready means it wont work..

Check your code in jsfiddle
       http://jsfiddle.net/mNq5X/

```
   <div class="pac-container">
   <div class="pac-item remove">This is me </div>
   <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>ustralia</div>
   <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>bbas Town, Karachi, Sind, Pakistan</div>
   <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>ustria</div>
   <div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>rgentina</div><div class="pac-item"><b>A</b>rizona</div>     
  </div>
```

js

```
$('.remove').live('click', function () {
  console.log("working");
});
```

So your solution is to add the above click function after appending the below div

```
          <div class="pac-item remove">This is me </div>
```

Comment: You don't need to the click binding **after** appending the div - the "on" binding needs configuring in the document ready event after which any dynamically added elements matching the selector will subscribe to the event.

Comment: @CSL Thank you...Now only i came to know that we can do this using document.on method.In past i used to do this in the above mentioned way. Hereafter i will use that document.on method.

Answer (score 0):

Since your div is appended dynamically, I think your click event code should be placed after the div is appended. Otherwise $('.remove') will return 'null', your click event will not work.